# Echoing <a> tag with PHP variables involved

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm looking to echo an hyperlink in a PHP file. The target and text are variables.
And no, I can't just make a html file and then echo out the variables. It has to be done with echoing out the statement.
I'm having problems with the " " around the target. The first " is okay, but the second is causing problems.
Here is my code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
if (!empty($row[adder])) {
echo "<a href=\"/".$row[adder].\"">".$row[adder]."</a>";
}
```

The problem is the \" after $row["adder'].

any idea why the error:

Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home//public_html/folder/index.php on line 116

is coming up??

I'm sure its just a missing " or something..

Thanks,
Niall

Comment: If you watch the syntax highlighting in your post you'll find the error, which Michiel Pater fixed in his answer. It's quite obvious if you analyze the colors. :)

Comment: Does your PHP editor support color coding/syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash needs to be shifted one position to the right. You can see where it goes wrong by the coloring.

Change this line:

```
echo "<a href=\"/".$row[adder].\"">".$row[adder]."</a>";
```

To:

```
echo "<a href=\"/".$row[adder]."\">".$row[adder]."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backslash is one `"` too soon:

```
echo "<a href=\"/".$row[adder]."\">".$row[adder]."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo '<a href="'.$row[adder].'">'.$row[adder].'</a>';
```